# flask_mysql is giving error "ExtDeprecationWarning: Detected extension named flaskext.mysql please rename it to flask_mysql."

Tags: python, mysql, import, python-import

I am using Python 2.7.5

I installed flask-mysql and so on... I already have a few database stored proc working  but i am having some issues with flask_mysql

anytime i run my code it it says:

```
api.py:5: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.mysql is deprecated, use flask_mysql instead.
from flask.ext.mysql import MySQL
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\exthook.py:106: ExtDeprecationWarning: Detected extension named flaskext.mysql, 
please rename it to flask_mysql. The old form is deprecated.
.format(x=modname), ExtDeprecationWarning
```

here is how i imported flask_mysql

```
from flask.ext.mysql import MySQL
```

my question is how do i import flask_mysql the right way or is their any other better alternative i could use to replace it

Comment: And your question is ... ? Also, I'm wondering why every time someone asks a question about an exception - he does not read it at all

Answer (score 0):

Your question already has an answer:
`Importing flask.ext.mysql is deprecated, use flask_mysql instead.`

So, as it says: replace `from flask.ext.mysql import MySQL` with `from flask_mysql import MySQL`.